# space around figures and how to remove it

Tags: spacing, lyx

I'm inputting several figures in my thesis and I'd like to know why there is always so much white space above and to the side of the figure and below the caption. Below the caption is particularly annoying but the 'offset' figure looks ugly too. Please see the [picture](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/5962491/Picture%202.png).  I've played with both the bounding box, the float dimensions, and figure dimensions.  Other than making it really small to fit, I haven't found a good solution (using LyX).  Suggestions?
Thanks
Dominik

EDIT: More info.  SInce setspace was returning an error saying spacing was already defined, I pulled this out of the custom .cls file.  ANy change this will garner an answer?

```
%%%%%%% DEFINE DOUBLE-SPACING (THE DEFAULT) AND OTHER SPACING:
\def\setspace@size{\ifx\@currsize\normalsize\@normalsize\else\@currsize\fi}
\def\doublespacing{ \ifcase \@ptsize \relax
       \def \baselinestretch {1.703}% 10pt -- EDIT (thesis=2.004; see line 251)
\or \def \baselinestretch {1.505}% 11pt -- EDIT (thesis=1.771; see line 252)
\or \def \baselinestretch {1.441}% 12pt -- EDIT (thesis=1.660; see line 253)
  \fi \setspace@size}
\def\singlespacing{\def \baselinestretch {1} \setspace@size \vskip \baselineskip}
\def\setstretch#1{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{#1}}
\def\@setsize#1#2#3#4{\@nomath#1
  \let\@currsize#1 \baselineskip #2
  \baselineskip \baselinestretch\baselineskip
  \parskip \baselinestretch\parskip
  \setbox\strutbox \hbox{ \vrule height.7\baselineskip depth.3\baselineskip
  width\z@} \skip\footins \baselinestretch\skip\footins
  \normalbaselineskip\baselineskip#3#4}
%%%%%%%%% floats & footnotes singlespaced %%%%%%%%%
\let\latexx@xfloat=\@xfloat
\def\@xfloat #1[#2]{\latexx@xfloat #1[#2]
\def\baselinestretch{1}\@normalsize \normalsize}
\long\def\@footnotetext#1{
  \insert\footins{
    \def\baselinestretch {1}
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \interlinepenalty\interfootnotelinepenalty
    \splittopskip\footnotesep
    \splitmaxdepth \dp\strutbox \floatingpenalty \@MM
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{
      \csname p@footnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}
    \color@begingroup \@makefntext{
        \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}
    \color@endgroup}}
\long\def\@mpfootnotetext#1{
  \global\setbox\@mpfootins\vbox{
    \unvbox \@mpfootins
    \def\baselinestretch {1}
    \reset@font\footnotesize
    \hsize\columnwidth \@parboxrestore
    \protected@edef\@currentlabel{
      \csname p@mpfootnote\endcsname\@thefnmark}
    \color@begingroup \@makefntext{
       \rule\z@\footnotesep\ignorespaces#1\@finalstrut\strutbox}
   \color@endgroup}}
%%%%%%%% single / double spacing %%%%%%%%%
\def\singlespace{ \vskip \baselineskip \def\baselinestretch {1}
  \setspace@size \vskip -\baselineskip }
\def\endsinglespace{\par}
\def\spacing#1{ \par \begingroup \def\baselinestretch {#1} \setspace@size }
\def\endspacing{ \par \vskip \parskip \vskip \baselineskip
  \endgroup \vskip -\parskip \vskip -\baselineskip }
\def\doublespace{ \ifcase \@ptsize \relax
      \spacing{1.6}%1.703   10pt -- EDIT (thesis=2.004; see line 199)
  \or \spacing{1.4}%1.505   11pt -- EDIT (thesis=1.771; see line 200)
  \or \spacing{1.3  }%1.441 12pt -- EDIT (thesis=1.660; see line 201)
  \fi }
   \let\enddoublespace=\endspacing
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're using a `\baselinestretch` for spacing the text. Try using `\usepackage{setspace}` as explained here: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikibooks/en/wiki/LaTeX/Formatting#Line_Spacing

Comment: I tried inserting setspace into the preamble and got an error compiling: setstretch, singlespacing, doublespacing already defined.    I did some reading about baselinestretch and sounds like i definitely don't want to be using it.  I'm guessing the spacing is somehow defined in the .cls?  Is there a way to override them in the preamble?  I played with  \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{2} and    \selectfont but didn't notice any changes.          \usepackage[
    font=small,
    justification=justified,
    labelfont={bf,singlespacing},
    textfont=singlespacing
    ]{caption} ?    Thx for help

Comment: sorry, couldn't figure out how to format my last post

Comment: Could you post a minimal working example (http://minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html)?, then we can probably figure out a bit more. And if you enclose the stuff you want to format in `, then it's highlighted.

Comment: '\usepackage{ifthen}
\renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
   \@float{figure}
 }{%
   \@float{figure}[#1]%
 }%
 \centering
}{%
 \end@float
}


\renewenvironment{table}[1][]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{%
   \@float{table}
}{%
   \@float{table}[#1]%
 }%
 \centering
}{
 \end@float
}'

Comment: not really a MWE but this is basically all I have since I"m using LYX `usepackage{ifthen} \renewenvironment{figure}[1][]{% \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{% \@float{figure} }{% \@float{figure}[#1]% }% \centering }{% \end@float } \renewenvironment{table}[1][]{% \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}{% \@float{table} }{% \@float{table}[#1]% }% \centering }{ \end@float }`